# Congiuntivo/condizionale vs. futuro/futuro [futuro ipotetico]

Tags: grammar

> Tizio: "Caro Caio, fino a che non scendesse sotto il 11,5% Sempronio perderebbe voti che ha comunque guadagnato lui."

CONTESTO

Qui si fa riferimento a un tal Sempronio che è divenuto leader di un partito.

Subito dopo tale circostanza il partito, che era all'11,5%, è passato prima al 15%, ma dopo un po' ha iniziato a perdere voti passando al 14%, poi al 13% e ora al 12%.

DOMANDA

C'è qualcosa di sgrammaticato nell'affermazione di Tizio in ordine all'uso del congiuntivo 'scendesse'?

CONSIDERAZIONI

Io avrei detto:

> Tizio: "Caro Caio, fino a che non scenderà sotto il 11,5% Sempronio perderà voti che ha comunque guadagnato lui."

Secondo me, peraltro, la 'mia' versione conserva anche il carattere ipotetico ed eventuale che Tizio, forse, voleva assolutamente trasparisse nella di Lui versione originale.

Comunque, sempre secondo me, a voler proprio usare una forma farcita al congiuntivo, meglio sarebbe:

> Tizio: "Caro Caio, fino a che non dovesse scendere sotto il 11,5% Sempronio perderà voti che ha comunque guadagnato lui."

Che ne dite?

Comment: Why was a -1 cast to such an intersting question?

Comment: I think the downvote was casted because you didn't reference the source of such a (grammatically very bad) statement; it will keep look like a totally useless theoretical question until you expliciltly say where you heard / read such an (again, grammatically very bad) statement in first place.

Comment: Finché non sarà sceso sotto il 11,5%, Sempronio perderà voti ...

Comment: @kos Yes, but the question remains an interesting question. (PS: the past participle of 'cast' is 'cast' :)

Comment: Non sarà una domanda “che mondi possa aprirti”, ma non si merita un voto negativo. +1

Comment: Elberich, let me point out that I didn't mean to be harsh at all by the way, just trying to spot why your question was downvoted :)  some people have a problem with thoretical questions / questions asked out of curiosity (not me tough, and it doesn't make sense at all on a site like this one; hopefully that was not not the reason, however [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164436/302251)'s the related post on Meta.SE); probably some italian guy deemed this as very trivial question / a question showing a blatant lack of research, while indeed it isn't for someone learning the language.

Answer (score 2):

Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/finche/), la congiunzione "finché", che ha lo stesso uso dell'espressione "fino a che", è generalmente usata con il modo indicativo. Come si spiega nel Treccani, l'uso che se ne fa in una frase negativa indica che una cosa, la perdita di voti in questo esempio, non può accadere fino al momento in cui non se ne verifica un’altra, la scesa sotto il 11,5%. Cioè, la scesa sotto il 11,5% deve avvenire prima della perdita di voti.

Tenendo conto del fatto che la frase è in futuro, si tratta di una situazione nella quale si dovrebbe usare il [futuro anteriore](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/futuro-anteriore_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) in questo modo

> ... fino a che non sarà sceso sotto il 11,5%, Sempronio perderà voti ...

per esprimere che la scesa sotto il 11,5% dovrà avvenire prima della perdita di voti.

Comunque, l'[enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/futuro-anteriore_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) indica che «nel parlato l’uso temporale del futuro anteriore è piuttosto sporadico»: frequentemente «il rapporto di anteriorità tra due eventi collocati nel futuro non è segnalato». E fa questo esempio di tale fenomeno

> quando arriverà Luca, inizieremo a cenare

spiegando che «non vi è coincidenza temporale tra le due azioni; tuttavia si ricorre al futuro semplice in entrambe le proposizioni». Questo viene a significare che, nella lingua parlata, sarebbe usuale esprimere la frase così:

> ... fino a che non scenderà sotto il 11,5%, Sempronio perderà voti ...